# how to input value to manual remark and TourInfo Number of sabre vcr_display output

Tags: sabre

when using VCR_DisplayRQ the output contain manual remark and TourInfo. How to input data to this field and which wsdl

```
<ManualRemarks>
                        <!--Mandatory-->
                        <!--Repeat Factor=0-->
                        <!--"Text" is used to pass back miscellaneous free text related to manual remarks.-->
                        <Text>TEST0</Text>
                    </ManualRemarks>

<!--"Number" is used to return the tour number.-->
                    <TourInfo Number="IT066AK"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enter remarks etc with the Passenger Details RQ